# Combining multiple lists into dictionary using single list value as key

Tags: python, list, dictionary

**Background:** I'm converting a PDF of user messages into a text file and trying to rebuild the message threads in a structured data format.

**The problem:** I have built a function that scans each line of text, detects a `thread_id` and marks that line as belonging to the appropriate `thread_id` and then creates a list of lists structured as such:

```
thread_lines = [['1234567890', 'Dear James,']
                ['1234567890', 'See you soon.']
                ['5558881112', 'Foobar']]
```

Item 0 of each inner list is the `thread_id`. Ideally I'd like to create a dictionary where each `thread_id` is a key and all lines of the same `thread_id` are concatenated together as the corresponding value.

**The code:** I have a function, which I've omitted here, called `check_thread` that uses regex to identify `thread_id`. Below is the small function that scans and categorizes each line.

```
def thread_create(text):
    thread_lines = []
    thread_id = None
    thread_dict = {}

    for line in range(len( text )):
        # is line beginning of new thread?
        if 'Thread' in text[line]:
            if check_thread(text[line]) != None:
                thread_id = check_thread(text[line])
            elif check_thread(text[line+1]) != None:
                thread_id = check_thread(text[line+1])

        #line belongs to current thread, do something
        if thread_id != None:
            thread_lines.append([thread, text[line]])
```

Can anyone offer any advice, or perhaps a method to wrangling this data in the way I require?

Answer (score 2):

If I understood correctly, this should do it:

```
thread_lines = [['1234567890', 'Dear James,'],
                ['1234567890', 'See you soon.'],
                ['5558881112', 'Foobar']]


result = {}
for tid, sentence in thread_lines:
    result.setdefault(tid, []).append(sentence)

print(result)
```

**Output**

```
{'1234567890': ['Dear James,', 'See you soon.'], '5558881112': ['Foobar']}
```